# IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds and if condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, if-statement, series

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    Repo
    Out[624]: 

1             Instrument    Term Code  WTD Rate
2    GC_AUSTRIA_SUB_10YR          T-N     -0.49
3    GC_AUSTRIA_SUB_10YR            O -0.467643
4      R_RAGB_1.15_10/18          S-N -0.520299
5      R_RAGB_4.35_03/19          S-N -0.497759
6      R_RAGB_4.35_03/19          T-N      -0.5
7      R_RAGB_1.95_06/19          S-N -0.501478
8      R_RAGB_0.25_10/19          S-N -0.497765
```

I have an if condition which is dependent on the column "Instrument"

```
if condition:
   return Repo.loc[(Repo['Instrument']=='GC_LCH_BELGIUM') & (Repo['Term Code']=='T-N'),'WTD Rate'].iloc[0]
```

The issue is that the Instrument name sometimes does not exist and get an error  `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`

How can I say in the "if condition" that if the instrument does exist (or if there is an error) reverts back to default value of say 10.

I should point out that when  Instrument does not exist there is no row in the dataframe. therefore code that looks something like "is empty" would  not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem is filtering return empty `DataFrame`, so not possible select first value and error is raised.

So need check if [`empty`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html) with `if-else`:

```
if condition:
   a =  Repo.loc[(Repo['Instrument']=='GC_LCH_BELGIUM')&(Repo['Term Code']=='T-N'),'WTD Rate']
   return 'empty' if a.empty else a.iloc[0]
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael.  You are right the filtering returns empty dataframe. Your suggestion is working fine. I ll put it in my code. Thank you

Comment: @SBad - Glad can help! Nice day!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `next` and supply a default argument of `10`:

```
if condition:
    mask = (Repo['Instrument']=='GC_LCH_BELGIUM') & (Repo['Term Code']=='T-N')
    s = Repo.loc[mask, 'WTD']
    return next(iter(s), 10)
```

Internally, this works by raising a `StopIteration` error when the series is empty and reverting to the default value.

Comment: I like this code too, would never have thought of `next` :)

Answer (score 2):

Since there are chances that condition inside the accessor is not met you can always go for `try` and `except`  i.e

```
if condition :
    try:
       return Repo.loc[(Repo['Instrument']=='GC_LCH_BELGIUM')&(Repo['Term Code']=='T-N'),'WTD Rate'].iloc[0]
    except IndexError:
       return 10
```

Comment: This is very Pythonic, +1.

Comment: That is an interesting second solution.